# Trying to create a generalized function in PHP 5.2, error message not showing

Tags: php

Hi I am Trying to create a generalized function in PHP 5.2 and I am not able to get the error message to show. I am not sure on how I am to pass the variables to the validate function. How do I create an input variable equal to all input fields? Do I need to put all the inputs into an `array`? This may be a simple question for the experienced php programmers, for me I am still wrapping my head around everything php. I have included my code below. Thanks:

```
    <?php
      $debug=1;
      $output_form= true;
      //$valid_ = 0;
      //$error_text= "";


    function validateFormInput($input, $patterns, &$errors)
        {
            $valid_ = false;
            $new    =   false;
            foreach($input as $key => $value) {
                if(!preg_match($patterns[$key], $value, $match)) {
                    $new[$key]  =   $errors[$key];
                    //$output_form = false;
                }
                // Remove errors if validation is made
                else
                    unset($errors[$key]);
                              $valid_= true;
                         //$output_form = true; 
            }
            //$output_form = false;
            return $new;
        }

    //initialization
    $inputs = array(
        "fname" => '',
        "lname" => '',
        "phone" => '',
        "city" => '',
        "state" => '',
        );

    $patterns = array(
        "fname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
        "lname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
        "phone" => '/^(\(\d{3}\))(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})$/',
        "city" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$/',
        "state" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/',
        );

    $errors = array(
        "fname" => "Please enter your FIRST name between 2 and 15 letters.",
        "lname" => "Please enter your LAST name between 2 and 15 letters.",
        "phone" => "Please enter your phone number in (###)###-### format.",
        "city" => "Please enter your city name between 3 and 20 letters.",
        "state" => "Please enter your state's abbreviation (Example: CA).",
        );

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($debug) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($_POST);
                echo "</pre>"; 

                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($_FILES);
                //echo "</pre>"; 
            //die("temp stop point");
              } //debug only
                $fname=trim($_POST['fname']);
                $lname=trim($_POST['lname']);
                $phone=trim($_POST['phone']);
                $city=trim($_POST['city']);
                $state=trim($_POST['state']);


        $inputs =   $_POST;
        //$output_form = false;
        // Just unset the submit and pass the $_POST via $inputs
        unset($inputs['submit']);
    //$output_form = false;
        validateFormInput($inputs,$patterns,$errors);
      //$output_form = false;
        if($errors)
            echo implode("<br />",$errors);
        $mobile = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
             $output_form = false;  


    } 

    //if ($valid_) {$output_form =false;}

    //$not_valid = validateFormInput($inputs,$patterns,$errors);
    //if($not_valid)
        //echo implode("<br />",$not_valid);

    //$output_form = false;
       //else { $output_form = false;}

        ?>
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lesson 7</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="php">
    <meta name="keywords" content="php">
    <meta name="author" content="William Payne">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="formLayout">
<?php 
//form
  if ($output_form) {
?>
    <form action="<?=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <fieldset>
     <legend>Info</legend>
     <?=$error_text ?>
     <label>First Name:</label><input name="fname" type="text" value="<?=$fname; ?>"><br>
     <label>Last Name:</label><input name="lname" type="text" value="<?=$lname; ?>"><br>
     <label>Phone Number:</label><input name="phone" type="text" value="<?=$phone; ?>"><br>
     <label>City:</label><input name="city" type="text" value="<?=$city; ?>"><br>
     <label>State:</label><input name="state" type="text" value="<?=$state; ?>"><br>
     </fieldset>
     <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form> 
<?php
  } else {
    //replace_mobile();
    //Processing for database inclusion, email cofirmation can also go here, thank you
    //2nd way to Solve Not using regex preg_replace $p = $phone; <?="$p[1]$p[2]$p[3]$p[5]$p[6]$p[7]$p[9]$p[10]$p[11]$p[12]";//
    ?>       
 <p><strong><?="$welcome_msg"; ?></strong></p>  
 <p><strong><?="$lname".''.', '. "$fname";?></strong></p>
 <p><strong><?="$phone".''.', '."$mobile";?></strong></p>
 <p><strong><?="$city".''.', '."$state";?></strong></p> 
 <?php
  } //end if/else form output
?>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could pass the variables as an array then loop over them applying your patterns. So basically 3 arrays go into the function. You would store the errors by the way, then return the errors in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment, here is what I meant by passing the variables as an array then looping over them, applying your patterns, and passing `$errors` by reference:

```
$patterns = array(
    "fname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
    "lname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
    "phone" => '/^(\(\d{3}\))(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})$/',
    "city" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$/',
    "state" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/',
    );

$errors = array(
    "fname" => "Please enter your FIRST name between 2 and 15 letters.<br>",
    "lname" => "Please enter your LAST name between 2 and 15 letters.<br>",
    "phone" => "Please enter your phone number in (###)###-### format.<br>",
    "city" => "Please enter your city name between 3 and 20 letters.<br>",
    "state" => "Please enter your state's abbreviation (Example: CA).<br>",
    );

// Pass by ref--------------------------------vv
function validateFormInput($input, $patterns, &$errors)
    {
        $new    =   false;
        foreach($input as $key => $value) {
            if(preg_match($patterns[$key], $value, $match))
                unset($errors[$key]);
        }

        return (empty($errors));
    }

$valid  =   false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $inputs =   $_POST;
    unset($inputs['submit']);

    $valid  =   validateFormInput($inputs,$patterns,$errors);

    if(!empty($errors))
        echo implode("<br />",$errors);
}

if(!$valid) {
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="LastName" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="123-123-1233" />
    <input type="text" name="city" value="Reno" />
    <input type="text" name="state" value="NsrV" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php   }
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on your full code, I have revised the solution to be more comprehensive. All functions should be on their own pages and included at the top like `include(__DIR__."/functions/function.validateFormInput.php");` (ideally setting up and autoloader function for even more simplicity) This will help keep the page clean:

```
define("ERRMODE",true);

function validateFormInput($input)
    {
        $errors =   false;

        foreach($input as $key => $value) {
            $pattern    =   patternList($key);
            if(!$pattern)
                continue;

            if(!preg_match($pattern, trim($value), $match)) {
                $errors[$key]   =   errorMsg($key);
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }

function patternList($name = false)
    {
        $patterns = array(
            "fname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
            "lname" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2,15}$/',
            "phone" => '/^(\(\d{3}\))(\d{3}\-)(\d{4})$/',
            "city" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}$/',
            "state" => '/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/',
            );

        return (isset($patterns[$name]))? $patterns[$name]:false;
    }

function errorMsg($name = false)
    {
        $errors = array(
            "fname" => "Please enter your FIRST name between 2 and 15 letters.",
            "lname" => "Please enter your LAST name between 2 and 15 letters.",
            "phone" => "Please enter your phone number in (###)###-### format.",
            "city" => "Please enter your city name between 3 and 20 letters.",
            "state" => "Please enter your state's abbreviation (Example: CA).",
            );

        return (isset($errors[$name]))? $errors[$name]:false;
    }

function printPre($val = false)
    {
        ob_start();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $data;   
    }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(ERRMODE) { 
        echo printPre($_POST);
        echo printPre($_FILES); 
    }

    $errors         =   validateFormInput($_POST);
    $formValid      =   (empty($errors));

    $fname          =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
    $lname          =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
    $phone          =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']);
    $city           =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']);
    $state          =   htmlspecialchars($_POST['state']);
    $mobile         =   preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lesson 7</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="php">
<meta name="keywords" content="php">
<meta name="author" content="William Payne">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="formLayout">
<?php 
//form
  if (empty($formValid)) {
        if(!empty($errors))
            echo implode("<br />",$errors);
?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
     <fieldset>
     <legend>Info</legend>
     <?php echo $error_text ?>
     <label>First Name:</label><input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($fname))? $fname : ""; ?>"><br>
     <label>Last Name:</label><input name="lname" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($lname))? $lname : ""; ?>"><br>
     <label>Phone Number:</label><input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($phone))? $phone : ""; ?>"><br>
     <label>City:</label><input name="city" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($city))? $city : ""; ?>"><br>
     <label>State:</label><input name="state" type="text" value="<?php echo (!empty($state))? $state : ""; ?>"><br>
     </fieldset>
     <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form> 
<?php
  } else {
?>       
        <p><strong><?php echo "$welcome_msg"; ?></strong></p>  
        <p><strong><?php echo "{$lname}, {$fname}";?></strong></p>
        <p><strong><?php echo "{$phone}"; ?></strong></p>
        <p><strong><?php echo "{$city}, {$state}"; ?></strong></p> 
<?php
  }
?>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure exactly what you mean. What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: I revised my code above,with your changes I just need the form to show when errors are present, and not show when valid, I tried adding some logic  its just going through  even with errors

Comment: Oh, gotcha! You would use the same `if($errors)`. So, `if($errors) echo 'form here';`

Comment: You wouldn't do it in your function. The function just returns an `array()` (true) if errors or `false` if no errors.

Comment: I tried using this logic-  if($errors)
        echo $output_form = true; 
        echo implode("<br />",$errors);
    } else { echo $output_form = true; that catches all the errors, still returns form. I have an if $output_form var above my html form then an else below the form where my data shows. that way the form doesnt show when all conditions are met and only shows when errors are. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Alright, take a look. I had to revise how the function returned, but it works pretty much the same...

Comment: Hmmm, now that I have seen your whole page, my solution is not as ideal because of the way you are separating things. Let me take your entire page and work out a better solution.

Comment: you really taught me how arrays work, everything works great, Thanks for your solid effort and patience with a newbie in php, you don't know how much this has helped. I was able to incorporate your changes and fit them within my code. All is good.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

**PHP:**

```
// Errors array.
$errArray = [];

//function
function validateFormInput($input, $fieldName, $isRequired, $min, $max, $patterns, $example = '') {

           // Trimming the input to get rid of empty spaces on the sides
           $input = trim($input);

           // If the provided value of required == 'yes', and variable is -
           // empty add an error to the errors array.
           if($isRequired == 'yes' && empty($input)){
             $errArray[] = $fieldName. ' is required';
           }else{

                // If the input is less than min or more than max -
                //compose the error and add it to the errors array.
                if(strlen($input) < $min || strlen($input) > $max ){
                    $errArray[] = 'Please enter your ' .$fieldName.' between ' .$min. ' and ' .$max. ' letters.<br>';
                }

               // Checking against the given pattern.the array.
               if(!preg_match($patterns, $input)){

                   //if the given example is not empty, add it to the error message.
                   $example = ($example) ? ', (Example: ' .$example. ')' : '';
                   $errArray[] = 'Wrong format of ' .$fieldName . $example;

               }
           }
    }
```

When you try to check a variablen input, says `$foo`:

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
validateFormInput($foo, 'Foo name', 'yes', 5, 20, '/^[a-zA-Z]$/');
```

So for the above, the parameters are:

- $foo = `$input` , the input value.
- $fieldName = `Foo Name` , the input name in the error message.
- $isRequired = `yes`, checks whether it is required or not.
- $min = `5` , the min allowed characters.
- $max = `20` , max allowed characters
- $pattern = `'/^[a-zA-Z]$/'` , the pattern to check against.
- $example = `''` , I didn't provide an example, but here it could be `(Example: CA)` or `(###)###-### format`.

Finally we check if the `$errArray` is empty, then no erros found, else we loop through the errors array and `echo` out all caught errors.

Comment: so I would create 5 diff function calls validateFormInput($foo, 'Foo name', 'yes', 5, 20, '/^[a-zA-Z]$/'); then just change the vars,regex,yes,5,20 to meet the 4 other input requirements?